# Rails datetime_select: 1 error(s) on assignment of multiparameter attributes [error on assignment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How do I get the parameters of datetime_select to save?

Error parameters:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
"authenticity_token"=>"/Tu18E4ubxp0XWcoLTdrm2B4Ho80PDH86dWwm9fvEMs=",
"post"=>{"title"=>"asdf",
"event_date(1i)"=>"2015",
"event_date(2i)"=>"8",
"event_date(3i)"=>"7",
"event_date(4i)"=>"15",
"event_date(5i)"=>"26",
"description"=>"asdf",
"published"=>"0"},
"button"=>""}
```

The model:

```
class Spree::Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :title, :description, :event_date

  def event_date
  end

  scope :published, lambda { where(:published => true) }
  scope :latest, order("created_at DESC").limit(3)
end
```

Relavent controller code:

```
def create
    @post = Spree::Post.new(post_params)
    if @post.save
      flash[:notice] = "Post saved successfully"
      redirect_to admin_posts_path
    else
      flash[:alert] = "There was an error saving your post"
      redirect_to :back
    end
end
```

And the view:

```
<p><%= f.label :event_date, Spree::Post.human_attribute_name(:event_date) %></p>
<p><%= f.datetime_select :event_date %></p>
```

The problem seems to be that it's trying to store multiple values. I'm guessing that the fix will be by adding to the model file, right?

Answer (score 0):

Have you permitted `event_date` in your `post_params`? (We don't know, because you didn't include your entire posts controller file.) If you haven't already permitted them, you might want to try editing your `post_params` to look like:

```
class Spree::PostsController < ActionController::Base

  private

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:event_date)
  end

end
```

See http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html for more information.

EDIT: Actually, given the snippet of your error message you provided, I'm less confident you have a strong parameters problem. I'll still keep this answer up, though.

Comment: Yes, I have permitted `event_date` in the `post_params`

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly permit each parameter part

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit("event_date(1i)","event_date(2i)","event_date(3i)","event_date(4i"),"event_date(5i)",:any,:other,:post,:fields)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should ensure that your field is a datetime in your database. If it is a string it will throw this error message when you try to save the datetime_select.